# Conky block padding Archlinux

Tags: arch-linux, conky

I'm not sure if my question was discussed lately and that's why create new topic.
The problem is that my conkу widget not looking as I want it to.

Because of image size I decided to put it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AVVF.jpg). 
My question is how to get around tabifying and padding in outlined areas?

Here is my `.conkyrc`

```
    alignment top_right
    background no

    use_xft yes
    xftfont Verdana:size=9

    update_interval 1.0
    double_buffer yes

    border_width 0
    cpu_avg_samples 2

    default_color white                                                                                                                                                                     
    default_outline_color white                                                                                                                                                             
    default_shade_color white                                                                                                                                                               

    draw_borders no                                                                                                                                                                         
    draw_graph_borders yes                                                                                                                                                                  
    draw_outline no
    draw_shades no

    gap_x 32
    gap_y 32
    maximum_width 256

    net_avg_samples 2
    out_to_console no
    out_to_stderr no
    extra_newline no

    own_window yes
    own_window_class Conky
    own_window_type override
    own_window_transparent yes

    stippled_borders 0
    uppercase no
    use_spacer none
    show_graph_scale no
    show_graph_range no

    TEXT
    $nodename @ $sysname $kernel | $machine | $freq_g GHz
    $hr

    ${color darkgrey}Uptime:$color $uptime
    ${color darkgrey}Processes:$color $processes

    ${color darkgrey}File systems:
        $color${fs_used /} / ${fs_size /}
        ${fs_bar 4 /}
        ${voffset -15}${color darkgrey}${cpubar cpu128 4}

    ${color darkgrey}RAM Usage:
        $color$mem / $memmax | $memperc%
        ${membar 4}
        ${voffset -15}${color darkgrey}${cpubar cpu128 4}
        ${color darkgrey}${memgraph FFFFFF FFFFFF}

    ${color darkgrey}CPU Usage:
        $color$cpu%
        ${cpubar 4}
        ${voffset -15}${color darkgrey}${cpubar cpu128 4}
        ${color darkgrey}${cpugraph cpu0 FFFFFF FFFFFF}

    ${color darkgrey}Networking:
        ${color darkgrey}Down: $color${downspeedf enp0s3}k/s ${alignr}${totaldown enp0s3} total
        ${color darkgrey}${downspeedgraph enp0s3 FFFFFF FFFFFF}
        ${color darkgrey}Up: $color${upspeedf enp0s3}k/s ${alignr}${totalup enp0s3} total
        ${color darkgrey}${upspeedgraph enp0s3 FFFFFF FFFFFF}

    ${color darkgrey}Process Name:          PID   CPU%   MEM%
        $color${top name 1} ${color darkgray}${top pid 1} ${top cpu 1} ${top mem 1}
        $color${top name 2} ${color darkgray}${top pid 2} ${top cpu 2} ${top mem 2}
        $color${top name 3} ${color darkgray}${top pid 3} ${top cpu 3} ${top mem 3}
        $color${top name 4} ${color darkgray}${top pid 4} ${top cpu 4} ${top mem 4}
        $color${top name 5} ${color darkgray}${top pid 5} ${top cpu 5} ${top mem 5}
        $color${top name 6} ${color darkgray}${top pid 6} ${top cpu 6} ${top mem 6}
        $color${top name 7} ${color darkgray}${top pid 7} ${top cpu 7} ${top mem 7}
        $color${top name 8} ${color darkgray}${top pid 8} ${top cpu 8} ${top mem 8}
        $color${top name 9} ${color darkgray}${top pid 9} ${top cpu 9} ${top mem 9}

    ${color darkgrey}Available updates: $color${execpi 3600 checkupdates | wc -l}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've ended up with this config. It supposed to work on low res(15.6) displays and conky 1.9.0-4.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjhyn.jpg)

Maybe this will save someone a couple of hours.

---

Complete listing for interested persons:

```
alignment top_right
background no

use_xft yes
xftfont Verdana:size=9

update_interval 1.0
double_buffer yes

border_width 5
border_margin 9
border_inner_margin 5
cpu_avg_samples 2

default_color white
default_outline_color white
default_shade_color white

draw_borders no
draw_graph_borders yes
draw_outline no
draw_shades no

gap_x 10
gap_y 0
minimum_size 250 5
maximum_width 300

net_avg_samples 2
out_to_console no
out_to_stderr no
extra_newline no

own_window yes
own_window_class Conky
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_type normal
own_window_transparent no
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
own_window_argb_visual yes
own_window_argb_value 0

stippled_borders 0
uppercase no
use_spacer yes
show_graph_scale no
show_graph_range no

TEXT
$nodename @ $sysname $kernel | $machine | $freq_g GHz
$hr

${color darkgrey}Uptime:$color $uptime
${color darkgrey}Processes:$color $processes

${color darkgrey}File systems:
    $color${fs_used /} / ${fs_size /}
    ${fs_bar 4 /}
    ${voffset -15}${color darkgrey}${cpubar cpu128 4}

${color darkgrey}RAM Usage:
    $color$mem / $memmax | $memperc%
    ${membar 4}
    ${voffset -15}${color darkgrey}${cpubar cpu128 4}
    ${color darkgrey}${memgraph FFFFFF FFFFFF}

${color darkgrey}CPU Usage:
    $color$cpu%
    ${cpubar 4}
    ${voffset -15}${color darkgrey}${cpubar cpu128 4}
    ${color darkgrey}${cpugraph cpu0 FFFFFF FFFFFF}

${color darkgrey}Networking:
    ${color darkgrey}Down: $color${downspeedf enp0s3}k/s ${alignr}${totaldown enp0s3} total
    ${color darkgrey}${downspeedgraph enp0s3 FFFFFF FFFFFF}
    ${color darkgrey}Up: $color${upspeedf enp0s3}k/s ${alignr}${totalup enp0s3} total
    ${color darkgrey}${upspeedgraph enp0s3 FFFFFF FFFFFF}


${color darkgrey}Process Name: ${goto 150}  PID ${goto 200} CPU% ${goto 250} MEM%
    $color${top name 1} ${goto 120} ${color darkgray}   ${top pid 1}    ${top cpu 1}    ${top mem 1}
    $color${top name 2} ${goto 120} ${color darkgray}   ${top pid 2}    ${top cpu 2}    ${top mem 2}
    $color${top name 3} ${goto 120} ${color darkgray}   ${top pid 3}    ${top cpu 3}    ${top mem 3}
    $color${top name 4} ${goto 120} ${color darkgray}   ${top pid 4}    ${top cpu 4}    ${top mem 4}
    $color${top name 5} ${goto 120} ${color darkgray}   ${top pid 5}    ${top cpu 5}    ${top mem 5}
    $color${top name 6} ${goto 120} ${color darkgray}   ${top pid 6}    ${top cpu 6}    ${top mem 6}
    $color${top name 7} ${goto 120} ${color darkgray}   ${top pid 7}    ${top cpu 7}    ${top mem 7}
    $color${top name 8} ${goto 120} ${color darkgray}   ${top pid 8}    ${top cpu 8}    ${top mem 8}
    $color${top name 9} ${goto 120} ${color darkgray}   ${top pid 9}    ${top cpu 9}    ${top mem 9}

${color darkgrey}Available updates: $color${execpi 3600 checkupdates | wc -l}
```